# Apache - Two VirtualHosts to different workers

Tags: apache, virtualhost, mod-jk

I have an application running on 4 back-end JBoss servers. Those servers are behind an Apache web server. Currently, i call my application with my.app1.com (just an example) and the request goes to one of the back-end servers.

What I would like to do, is to call my application with another domain as well, like my.app2.com. And here is the tricky part of what I'm trying to achieve - When I call the application with my.app1.com, I want the request to go to two of the first back-end servers (or get served by two of the workers), and when I call it with my.app2.com, I want the request to go to the other two back-end servers (or get served by the other two workers).

I thought that I could achieve this by creating two different VirtualHost sections, where in each one I would call a different workers.properties file by using the property `JkWorkersFile path/to/workers.properties` inside the VirtualHost. But after reloading the configuration, I found that JkWorkersFile cannot be used inside VirtualHost. And to give an example of what I had done:

My `VirtualHost` sections look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                 
    ServerName my.app1.com
    <....Other configuration here....>
    JkWorkersFile path/to/workers1.properties
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                 
    ServerName my.app2.com
    <....Other configuration here....>
    JkWorkersFile path/to/workers2.properties
</VirtualHost>
```

My workers1.properties file looks like:

```
worker.instance1.reference=worker.template
worker.instance1.host=localhost 
worker.instance1=10109 
worker.instance1.domain=group1

worker.instance2.reference=worker.template
worker.instance2.host=localhost 
worker.instance2=10109 
worker.instance2.domain=group1
```

My workers2.properties file looks like:

```
 worker.instance3.reference=worker.template
    worker.instance3.host=localhost 
    worker.instance3=10109 
    worker.instance3.domain=group2

    worker.instance4.reference=worker.template
    worker.instance4.host=localhost 
    worker.instance4=10109 
    worker.instance4.domain=group2
```

But as I wrote above, using JkWorkersFile inside VirtualHost does not work.

I read on some other forums, that one can use JkMount (since it can be used many times) and give it as a parameter/value the name of the worker. But that didn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this. Posting the answer here in case anybody runs into the same request.

What was needed was to create a second loadbalancer worker and assign to it the back-end instances you want. In the workers.properties (no need for multiple  worker.properties files) among other configurations, i have the following for the two loadbalancer workers (Note, it is a different thing a loadbalancer worker, and a different thing a back-end worker, I came to realize):

```
worker.list=loadbalancer1,loadbalance2,status
```

(for the below 4 is up to you what methods you want to use)

```
worker.loadbalancer1.method=B
worker.loadbalancer1.lock=P
worker.loadbalancer2.method=B
worker.loadbalancer2.lock=P

.....here goes the list of back-end workers as stated above....
```

And here is first the crucial part:

```
worker.loadbalancer1.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer1.balance_workers=LIST1_OF_BACKEND_WORKERS_YOU_WANT_TO_ASSIGN
worker.loadbalancer1.sticky_session=True
worker.loadbalancer1.retries=1

worker.loadbalancer2.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer2.balance_workers=LIST2_OF_BACKEND_WORKERS_YOU_WANT_TO_ASSIGN
worker.loadbalancer2.sticky_session=True
worker.loadbalancer2.retries=1

worker.status.type=status
```

Then under conf.d I have a file called uriworkermap.properties where I have the following, which tells to each of the two loadbalancer workers to send the requests to the back-end (that is, to the instances assigned to them):

```
/*=loadbalancer1;
/*=loadbalancer2;
```

Then I have configured two VirtualHosts, each listening on a different domain name (as shown also above):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                 
    ServerName my.app1.com
    <....Other configuration here....>
    JkMount /* loadbalancer1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                 
    ServerName my.app2.com
    <....Other configuration here....>
    JkMount /* loadbalancer2
</VirtualHost>
```

In simple words, the line `JkMount /* loadbalancer{N}` tells each VirtualHost to send all requests to the specified loadbalancer, which in turn will forward the request to the back-end workers assigned to it.

That's it! Reload your Apache and you're basically accessing you application with two domain names, and each of them has it's own back-end workers.

Comment: This is a good answer to a good question. You should click the Accept (checkmark) button to mark it as answered.